How do I migrate Auth0 rules to actions
I am currently trying to migrate our Auth0 rule to actions. When I take a simple rule that successfully adds a custom role to the token and migrate it to an action the role doesnt show up in the token.
Rule
function (user, context, callback) {
  if (context.clientName === 'MyClientName') {
    var namespace = 'https://ournamespace.com/';
    var roles = [];

    roles.push('testRole');

    if (context.accessToken) {  
      context.accessToken[namespace + 'email'] = user.email;
      context.accessToken[namespace + 'scopes'] = roles.join(' ');
    }
  
    try {
      user.team_scopes = roles.join(' ');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  
    callback(null, user, context);
  } else {
    callback(null, user, context);
  }
}

Result
{
  "name": "My Name",
  "email": "myEmail@email.com",
  "team_scopes": "testRole",
  "iss": "****",
  "sub": "****",
  "aud": "****",
  "iat": ****,
  "exp": ****
}

Action
exports.onExecutePostLogin = async (event, api) => {
  const namespace = 'https://ournamespace.com/';
  let roles = [];
  roles.push('TestRole');
  console.log(`Adding roles to token: ${roles.join(' ')}`);
  api.accessToken.setCustomClaim(`${namespace}team_scopes`, roles.join(' '));
};

Result
{
  "name": "My Name",
  "email": "myEmail@email.com",
  "iss": "****",
  "sub": "****",
  "aud": "****",
  "iat": ****,
  "exp": ****
}

I've tried disabling the rule so only the action is there.
The rule and action are named the same.
it almost seems like the action isnt being triggered because when I run it from the Auth0 UI and I seem to get the expected result.
Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Are you certain that the action is being set after everything has loaded?  Like, after the call has been made and the promise returns with data?

what do you mean? The code hasnt changed, my understanding is that it doesnt need to. Also the Action has been deployed. When I test through the Auth0 portal and put logging into it I can see the expected result

I just meant that for Auth0, you made certain that whatever script that you're firing, you had made certain that it had all loaded properly given that you are 'marrying' two systems. To cut it down to barebones, is there some other field that both the auth0 and action share that you could also test.  Just to see that something is changing and you can rule out whether it's the call/promise/order of operations.

Silly question: did you deploy that Action and attach it to the Login flow?
https://auth0.com/docs/customize/actions/write-your-first-action#deploy-the-action

SOLUTION: This issue was that you needed to add a trigger in the portal. (i cant answer my own question for some reason so i added the comment here)
